# Group by Pandas and replace null value by value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge Pandas dataframe df with over 4 million rows which looks like below.

```
         id      value        percent  value_1  percent_1
 0      1       0.530106      21%-31%       NaN     NaN
 1      2       0.086647      10%-20%       NaN     NaN
 2      3       0.073121      $30%-40%      NaN     NaN
 3      4       0.76891       81%-90%       NaN     NaN
 4      5       0.86536       41%-50%       NaN     NaN
 5      1          NaN          NaN     0.630106    91%-100%    
 6      2          NaN          NaN     0.086647    11%-20%  
 7      3          NaN          NaN     0.073121    $0%-10%   
 8      4          NaN          NaN     0.376891    81%-90%    
 9      5          NaN          NaN     0.186536    41%-50%
```

I want a dataframe that looks like the below

```
          id         value        percent  value_1  percent_1
 0      1       0.530106    21%-31%     0.630106    91%-100%
 1      2       0.086647    10%-20%     0.086647    11%-20%
 2      3       0.073121    $30%-40%    0.073121    $0%-10%
 3      4       0.76891     81%-90%     0.376891    81%-90% 
 4      5       0.86536     41%-50%     0.186536    41%-50%
```

One hacky way to do this is replace NaN with empty string, convert the entire df columns into strings and  group them

```
 df = df.replace(np.nan,'')
 df = df.astype(str)
 df.groupby(['id']).sum()
```

But this takes a long time because groupby takes a lot of time with strings. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try `groupby` with `first` which will skip the NaN value

```
df=df.groupby('id').first().reset_index()
```